# why am i getting Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

im trying to make a chrome extension and i cant get my code to run.
this is the manifest

```
  {
  "name": "My First Extension",
   "version": "1.0",
   "description": "The first extension that I made.",
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon.png"
 },
 "background_page": "background.html",
 "permissions": [
 "*://*",
"tabs"
]
}
```

and this is my background.html

```
 <body>
<script>
chrome.tabs.OnCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    alert("fooooooo");

});
</script>
</body>
```

and in the chrome debugger i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined.

ive set the permissions correctly i think, but now i really dont know how to fix this. can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `OnCreated` it should be `onCreated`. JavaScript is case sensitive.